# What is the name of these creatures in Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter, character-identification, magical-creatures

There are creatures I cannot identify in ***Deathly Hallows***, when Harry is looking for [Rowena Ravenclaw's Diadem.](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Horcrux)

I haven't been able to find the name of these creatures anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Per Pottermore

> The [Cornish pixies](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Pixie) make their second appearance in the Room of
> Requirement in Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows – Part 2.
>
> <sub><sup>[Behind the scenes: Cornish pixies](https://www.pottermore.com/features/behind-the-scenes-cornish-pixies)</sup></sub>

These are, of course, the same kind of pixies (possibly even the *very same pixies* given that Lockhart would have had no further need for them) that Harry valiantly fought against in Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets.

Comment: *Cornish Pixies?!?*

Comment: @TheDarkLord - *Freshly caught* Cornish Pixies.

Comment: I don't think they're freshly caught after 5 years.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez - Yeah, probably a bit ripe by then.